# UITableview Push Detail

Tags: uitableview, push

in my application i  have a table view push to a view controller but i want to have the table view push to a new table view how would i approach this?

this is how i am performing the segue now

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    int row = [myIndexPath row];
    detailViewController.DetailModal = @[_Title[row], _Description[row], _Images[row]];
}
}
```

this work when pushing to a view controller but not a table view controller how do i make it go to a new table view?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're doing the Geeky Lemon Tutorial found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-K7j-nnRCdA). When you create the second tableView make sure you set the custom identifier to "DetailViewController".

Hope it helps.